# Android Wear Smartwatch notification with multiple pages - small icon only shows up on 1st page?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, wear-os

So I have set up a 2-page Android wear notification (dispatched from the device) as such:

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder mainNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setStyle(bigStyle)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
android.app.Notification secondNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setLargeIcon(balanceBackgroundImage)
            .setStyle(bigStyle2)
            .build();
android.app.Notification twoPageNotif = mainNotificationBuilder
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                    .setContentIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setBackground(backgroundImage)
                    .addPage(secondNotification)
            )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .build();
```

However, the small icon only appears on the first page, but I want it to appear on both!

Is this even possible? I have a feeling that its not, and that the icon can only appear on the first page of a multi-page watch notification, but I wanted to get confirmation from you all.

Thanks in advance :\

Comment: Why do you want the small icon to also appear on the second page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct: the small icon only appears on the first page of a notification.